# Team foundation User Permission

Tags: user-permissions

we are working on a project using C#,5 developers, we are using team foundation to share the code between the developers. each developer can check in and edit only his part and he is allowed to view other developers parts.

we are adding a new member to the group for a temporarily period.

the permission i want to give him is:
- CANT view any source code but his part
- edit and check in/check out for his code.

we dont want him to view any of our code but he will use some of our methods, we only wants him to view these classes. but other classes we want them to be disappeared.

how to do this?

I am using tfs 2010

Comment: I don't use TFS so I cannot help, but is hiding code really useful nowadays? I often look into other people's code (including system libraries) because code itself is the most exact documentation of the code. Disassemblers are everywhere. What good is it to hide code?

Comment: company policy, and because the new developer is outsourced, so we dont want him to steal the code or something. i am just a dveloper but this is company policy, no code should leaked out of the company.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be project admin to be able to add TFS groups and update permissions/security.

`Team Explorer` > right click on the team project > `Team Project Settings` > `New` > add Group Name e.g. Contractors > `Ok` > double click on the group name > add the contractor > `Ok`

Then right click on the individual folders/files in source control > `Properties` > `Security` > `Add TFS Group` > select your new group > select permissions for that group for that folder/file.

You can prevent the contractor from accessing code by checking the `Read` permission's `Deny` check box.